# Erro em instrução SQL

Tags: sql, sql-select, join

Tenho a seguinte BD:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando executo a seguinte Query:

```
SELECT 
   tbCelula.*
FROM 
   (((tbTiposMonitorizacao 
INNER JOIN 
   tbMonitorizacaoProj ON tbTiposMonitorizacao.TM_ID = tbMonitorizacaoProj.MP_T_ID) 
INNER JOIN 
   tbListaConformidades ON tbMonitorizacaoProj.MP_ID = tbListaConformidades.L_MP_ID) 
 INNER JOIN 
   tbCelula ON tbTiposMonitorizacao.TM_ID = tbCelula.C_TM_ID) 
 INNER JOIN 
   tbValores ON (tbListaConformidades.L_ID = tbValores.V_L_ID) 
 AND 
   (tbCelula.C_ID = tbValores.V_C_ID)
WHERE 
   (((tbListaConformidades.L_ID)=21));
```

A instrução não me devolve todos os dados que eu pertendo consultar.

Output:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resultado esperado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A coluna V_ID é uma chave primária, portanto não pode ser vazia. Porque no resultado esperado alguns campos estão com a chave primária vazia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provavelmente quando você executa este

```
INNER JOIN  tbValores ON (tbListaConformidades.L_ID = tbValores.V_L_ID)
```

teu select só vai trazer os registros onde `tbListaConformidades.L_ID = tbValores.V_L_ID`. Toda vez que você faz inner join, a consulta só irá retornar onde tenha registros em todas as tabelas. Faça o teste e add valores aos registros que estão em branco e você vai ver que o eles irão aparecer na consulta.
Exemplo 1: temos um registro onde `tbListaConformidades.L_ID = 7` *porém não tem nenhum registro onde* `tbValores.V_L_ID = 7`, então será descartado da consulta e irá para o próximo.
Exemplo 2: **Temos** `tbListaConformidades.L_ID = 3` e **TEMOS** `tbValores.V_L_ID = 7`, ai sim será imprimido no retorno da consulta.